# EF6 load a property of related collection member

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6

If I have classes `Account`, `AccountImage` and `Image`

```
public class Account{

   public virtual List<AccountImage> AccountImages{get;set;}
}


public class AccountImage{

   public virtual Image Image {get;set;}
}


public class Image{
   public string ImageUrl {get;set;}
}
```

I have an `Account` object want to load `Image` references of the `AccountImages` collection.

I can load `AccountImages` like this,

```
Db.Entry(v.acc).Collection(e => e.AccountImages).Load();
```

but how ca I load `Image` without resorting to

```
foreach(var ai in v.acc.AccountImages){
    Db.Entry(ai).Reference(e => e.Image).Load();
}
```

and inducing multiple db hits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid foreach loop in explicit load, you can load navigation properties eagerly:

```
var acc = db.Accounts.Include(a => a.AccountImages.Select(ai => ai.Image));
```